# How can I filter an array to the first record?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

There may be a better way to do this, but I am trying to filter a SharePoint List to a single line item based on a unique column that isn't the actual ID.

I have a variable at the beginning of the flow that captures the Name (this column is unique). I'd like to then go to SharePoint and "Get Item" to grab that specific record, but the issue I am running into is that it requires an actual ID rather than just a unique identifier such as Name.

From there, my head went to "Get Items" and "Filter Array" based on Name. The issue with this is that I am trying to initialize a variable at the end that will reference the Birthday of the line item and you cannot do this within an Apply to Each.  Is there a way around this? Better way to do this?

My Table:

```
ID | Name | Location | Birthday
--------------------------------
1  | Rob  | Chicago  | 02-09-2000
2  | Tim  | Denver   | 05-25-1998
...
```

At the end of the day, I am pretty much trying to do a VLOOKUP with variables as inputs and outputs (if the input is Rob, then create a variable = 02-09-2000), as this is the required format for the rest of the flow

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint` action instead of `Get items`. It is not premium and more flexible. It uses ODATA query syntax. [Here is a good](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/) ODATA reference doc.

- Set the URI to `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('enterYourListName')`
- Set the filter criteria to `$filter=Name eq` then the Name variable you mentioned using Dynamic Content.
- You may have to put single quotes around the Dynamic Content.
- Also pay special attention to the headers required

It can be finicky at first, but once you get it dialed, this is a far superior action than `Get items`.

Here are some [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest) docs to [study](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#supported-odata-query-options).